# Break up big array into smaller arrays, or break up a big text string into smaller strings - javascript

Tags: javascript

What is the method for breaking up a big array into smaller arrays. Or a big text string into smaller strings in javascript.

Ex: I have a string of 49 words separated by spaces/commas.  I want to break it up into smaller strings of 10 words and the 9 remainder string.  Same for an 49-element array.

Is there a prebuilt method for this?

TIA

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split array into chunks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To split up a string, use: `string.split`. If you want to split a string which is separated by a comma, use `string.split(',')`.

When you want to split a string in parts of 10 characters, use:

```
var string = "15dsck3c rando mstring esjldf bjk";
var match = string.match(/[\S\s]{10}|[\S\s]{0,9}$/g); //{10} = 10 characters;
var listOfWords = Array.apply(null, match);
```

Splitting an array can be done by using the `array.slice` method (which does *not* modify the array).

```
var arr = ["big", "small", "huge", "wall", "of", "text", "etc", "etc"];
var newList = [];
for(var i=0, len=arr.length; i<len; i+=10){
    newList.push(arr.slice(i));
}
//newList is an array consisting of smaller arrays, eg 
// [["big", <9 other elements>], [<10 elements>], ...]
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, your solution would work, I was hoping for a 1 line solution.  I guess JS does not have that built in function.

Comment: `string.split(",")` is a one line solution. I've just provided multiple solutions in my answer, so that you can choose your preferred method.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp

a more [general tutorial](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays).